# Copper acetate synthesis without hydrogen peroxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, home-experiment

Usually, when people synthesize copper acetate, they use a mixture of acetic acid and hydrogen peroxide. I assume this is because the acetic acid actually reacts with the various oxides on the copper, rather than with the copper itself. However, assuming I don't have access to hydrogen peroxide, can I do a similar thing (but slower), just by waiting until fresh copper surface is exposed and then taking it out. Then, I will heat it up (or just wait) until oxide layer forms again, and keep repeating until copper is corroded away.

Comment: You can electrolyze  a conc. aqueous solution of calcium acetate with copper electrodes. see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_acetate) for the description of the process.

Comment: Related: [Copper Doesn't React with Hydrochloric acid](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16507/7951)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I placed 1tbs salt, 1L vinegar, and 200g solid copper in a jar. After 3 months in a **dark** place the solution was extremely dark blue - so blue I couldn't see through it. This is what happened (bottom answer).
[How may copper acetate ligands be manipulated to change colors?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87/how-may-copper-acetate-ligands-be-manipulated-to-change-colors)

Heat may be able to substitute for time and quicken the formation of copper acetate...I really haven't tried. Peroxide is dirt cheap. I would have used it if I had known.

Comment: I think this at least tries to answer the question. It would be better with more explanation, but I see no reason to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

See my rapid prep ['Experimental Variants of Bleach Battery to Obtain Metal Oxides (like CuO)'](https://www.sciencemadness.org/whisper/viewthread.php?tid=84047#pid521659) where from Bleach (NaOCl), a piece of copper metal, and a noble metal cathode (nickel alloy coin), one can in a few minutes with microwave assisted heating, create a cloud of black CuO particles.

Add acetic acid to the CuO to prepare your Copper Acetate.